# Will static linking allow cross platform execution?

Tags: c, operating-system, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I am curious about how statically linked C executables would work in different environments. Lets say we compile our C code to target x86 MacOs and we statically include everything it uses in the executable as well (print, strlen). What really stops this executable from running in a Windows OS if we include every library it needs? I understand the file format could be different and break but other than that would this technically be able to run?

Comment: Static linking does not change the fact that the binary is OS specific.

Answer (score 6):

I see where you're coming from, operating systems makes us think as programmers that libraries are the be-all end-all of programming, that a call to a library is all you need to make complex things happen and that everything is contained in them.

But the truth is, libraries mostly provide an [abstraction layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer). As an example, let's create a library called "hello_world.so" which prints "Hello World!" to the console. That library we created relies on stdio to handle the complex I/O stuff but stdio itself depends on at least one other thing: the kernel (some specific targets work without a kernel but these system are outside the scope of this answer).

In the desktop world, things can get really complicated, we have several hundreds of processes all running at once even in an idle system, all these apps need access to the hardware (possibly at once too) so it was decided a controller was needed, some piece of software that would coordinate all other software running on the same computer. This piece of software is usually called a kernel. On Windows it's the NT kernel, on macOS it's the XNU and on Linux it's... the Linux kernel!

On these systems, the biggest job of a library is to abstract the kernel, to make us **believe** printing text on a Linux or a Windows console works the exact same way when actually it can be completely different! Libraries like stdio/time/etc have different "implementations" but the same "interface": they look the same from the dev point of view but the way they achieve their goals can vary wildy, they can do conversions, calls to other hidden or non hidden functions... All this is completely portable from one OS to the other though, things start to go south for you idea when kernel calls start to show up.

Kernel calls are ways a program can "talk" to the kernel. They can be used to do literally thousands of different things but for example there's one (or several ones)  to ask for memory (usually this is called with malloc), one to print to the console, one to ask if a network packet arrived, on to ask to talk to your GPU... And these system calls are **completely** different from one kernel to the other, sometimes even for two versions of the same kernel!

**These "kernel calls" are the only thing preventing you from running statically-compiled linux programs on Windows.**

PS: Even though all the above is completely true and kernels can be as different from one another as they wish, due to the history of kernels and of computing in general, some kernels actually share the same interface (even though their implementation as you guessed, can be nothing alike). The best example I know of is how most kernels I know of are based on the UNIX kernel.

It means that -even though I have never tested it myself- I think you should be able to statically link a Linux app and use it on Linux, most BSDs and possibly even macOS

Comment: Thank you, so even though "printf" is abstracted, the way "printf" will call on the kernel will be OS specific and cant be replicated on different kernels because its just not supported, even if we include static linking. Static linking doesnt include the kernel with the executable i guess.

Comment: Exactly, the only way for your software to be completely 100% OS agnostic is to run on bare metal (so without any OS at all) which, in 2021 is really not that great an idea, it's a lot easier to have 3 build machine automated through jenkins or some other CI software to produce and push the binaries to wherever you want them to be

Answer (score 0):

The binary and libraries are specific to the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

The **TLDR** is that the linking process translates function calls into adresses that points of the Operating System's specific libraries. There are some differences like alignment that happens at compile time, but the responsible for your x86 instructions not running under a different OS is the linker.

Your compiler produces x86 instructions that are ready to execute but is incomplete. The linker will go into every function call give a adress for that function in the executable file, even for functions of the standard library.

The linker will create the executable file following a file format which have a header with information like size, metadata and entry point.Windows and Unix have differents specifications for executable files. Windows has **PE** and Unix has **ELF** format both for executables and libraries.

Through some hacks and non-trivial tricks it is possible to create an executable that can run on Windows and Unix ([see αcτµαlly pδrταblε εxεcµταblε for how](https://justine.lol/ape.html)).

But even if you do all that there is an obstacle that can not be circumvented: the kernel. The kernel is, well, a kernel. It's the most important thing in
a OS and it provides a set of API calls that provides basic and low-level access to computer resources, so functions like malloc are implemented using the kernel specific API call, `VirtualAlloc` for Windows and `vmalloc` or `mmap` for POSIX.

Comment: Except for the last paragraph, that's only valid for dynamic libraries though (.dll on Win32, .so on Unix-like) the question is specifically about a completely static binary with no dynamic link whatsoever (built exclusively with .lib files in Win32, .a on Linux/BSDs/macOS)

Answer (score 0):

### Main Answer

If your program does anything useful (print output, return a value, communicate on the network), it contains some form of system-call instruction. Each system-call instruction is a request to a particular operating system, and macOS system calls will not work on Windows and vice-versa.

The system-call instruction sends information to the operating system, including a number identifying which service is requested. The operating system that performs that service. When you build your program for macOS, it includes library routines that contain system-call instructions. If you execute those instructions on a Microsoft Windows system, Windows will not understand the macOS requests. It will interpret the information differently, and the program will not work.

So, in theory, there is nothing preventing you from writing your own program loader that reads an ELF executable file intended for macOS, loading its contents into memory, and transferring control to its entry point. But the program will not work because of the system calls.

### Supplement

You might consider translating all the system calls in the program. Changing the primary number that identifies the service request might be feasible; it might not require changing the executable too much. For example, if 37 is a “write to file” request on macOS, your program loader might change it to 48 on Windows. However, the system calls also require other data be passed, such as pointers to buffers, lengths, and so on, and there are likely many discrepancies in how those are passed, so that macOS requests cannot be easily translated into Windows requests. Also, it can be technically challenging to identify all places in a program that a certain instruction is used—some of the contents of memory of a loaded program are instructions and some are data. Most normal programs may be well-behaved and easy to analyze in this regard, but not all are.

Another potential issue is that programs may expect to have certain modes set in the processor, and the host operating system may or may not have set those modes as needed.